# How can I get the color of the last figure in matplotlib?

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I'm plotting some data sets with linear fits. I want the linear fit to have the same color as the plotted data (error bars). How can I get that color?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might try this:

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
err = np.ones(10)
ebar = plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=err)
color = ebar[0].get_color()
```

`ebar` is a container of artist, so you might modify the index in the last line to match the artist you want to get color from.

You can also easily set the color of the errorbar, so you know exactly what color they are without checking it:

```
ebar = plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=err, ecolor='y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! This same trick works for plt.plot(...) as well.  I mention this because I found this answer helpful, but wasn't looking at using error bars, but rather to make three curves match in color.