# How to get color of most recent plotted line in Python's plt

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot a line without specifying the color (think: plt.plot(x,y)).
Say the color comes out blue.

**Question:** How do I obtain this color from the plt object so that I can put it into a variable?

Seems like this is close (and potentially the solution):

```
p = plt.plot(x,y)
color = p[0].get_color()
```

**Updated question:**
I am not sure I understand the "0" index: Does p[0] always access the most recent plotted line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the color of the last figure in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395888/how-can-i-get-the-color-of-the-last-figure-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I updated my question, thanks for pointing out the link

Comment: Since I was using subplots, this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042183/matplotlib-get-color-for-subplot) was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In your example, `p` is a list of `Line2D` object. In that example you have only one line object, `p[0]`. The following is an example plotting three lines. As more line is added, it is appended to the `p`. So if you want the color of the last plot, it will be `p[-1].get_color()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
p = plt.plot(x,y, x,y*2, x,y*3) # make three line plots
type(p) # list
type(p[0]) # <class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'>
p[0].get_color() # 'b'
p[1].get_color() # 'g'
p[2].get_color() # 'r'
```

[image: line plot]

Answer (score 43):

If you cannot access or store the return value of the call to `plt.plot`, you should also be able to use `plt.gca().lines[-1].get_color()` to access the color of the last line which was added to the plot.

In the following example, I'm creating example data, run `curve_fit` and show both data and fitted curve in the same color.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

m = 5
n = 3
x = np.arange(m)
y = np.array([i * x + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, len(x)) for i in range(n)])

def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

for y_i in y:
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y_i)
    plt.plot(x, y_i, linestyle="", marker="x")
    plt.plot(x, f(x, *popt), color=plt.gca().lines[-1].get_color())
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 16):

For regular `plt.plot`, doing `item.get_color()` on each element of the list it returns will get you the colors of each line.

But other plot functions, like `plt.scatter`, will return a `Collection`. For a `Collection`, you can call `result.get_facecolor()`. This will return an array of color values of the foreground colors of the elements. So if they're all the same color (as they are when you make a scatter plot with just X and Y values), `result.get_facecolor()[0]` will suffice.

Comment: What about the case in scatter where the color is set by a vector? How can one get the color per patch?