# matplotlib get_color for subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am following the tutorial from here: 
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html
However, the example used is for a single plot and I'm currently working with subplots. 
My version is the following:

```
    p1 = tr[names['equity']].plot(ax=ax3, linewidth = 0.75)
    axb = ax3.twinx()
    axb.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 0.5))
    p2 = tr[names[local_rating]].plot(ax=axb, c= 'r', linewidth = 0.75)
    axb.grid(False)
    axb.margins(x=0)
    axc = ax3.twinx()    
    p3 = tr[names['vol']].plot(ax=axc, c = 'g', linewidth = 0.75)
    axc.grid(False)
    axc.margins(x=0)
    ax3.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    axb.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
    axc.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())
```

When I try to do pX.get_color() I get:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_color'

My question is: **what method should I use to recover a subplot's color?**

I'm aware that I could manually set the color to match since it's a small number of instructions, but I'm just wondering if there is another way.

Thanks

Comment: I was working with `ax.bar` and wanted to get the latest color. Here's what did it for me in case anyone else runs into the same issue
`bars = ax.bar(x, height)` and `c = bars.patches[-1].get_facecolor()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has nothing to do with subplots. You are using the pandas plotting function instead of the matplotlib `plot` function as in the example.

An axes indeed has no color. If you are interested in the color of the lines inside the axes you may use e.g.

```
ax.get_lines()[0].get_color()
```

to get the color of the first line in the axes `ax`.

Comment: you're correct, changing to axX.get_lines()[0].get_color() works correctly now, thank you!

Comment: If you keep adding lines and want to get the color of the last line, use: `ax.lines[-1].get_color()`