# How to get color of most recent plotted line in pandas df.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I would like to get the color of the my last plot

```
ax = df.plot() 
df2.plot(ax=ax)
# how to get the color of this last plot, 
#the plot is a single timeseries, there is therefore a single color.
```

I know how to do it in `matplotlib.pyplot`, for those interested see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395888/how-can-i-get-the-color-of-the-last-figure-in-matplotlib) but I can't find a way to do it in pandas. Is there something acting like `get_color()` in pandas?

Comment: Try `ax.get_lines()[-1].get_color()`

Comment: @Goyo why is it a comment and not an answer? if you promote it, i'll mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: Because I wrote it from memory and didn't have a chance to test it. IIUC it worked for you so I elaborated it into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do the same with `DataFrame.plot` because it doesn't return a list of `Line2D` objects as `pyplot.plot` does. But `ax.get_lines()` will return a list of the lines plotted in the axes so you can look at the color of the last plotted line:

`ax.get_lines()[-1].get_color()`

Answer (score 1):

Notice (don't know if it was implicit in the answer by Goyo) that calls to pandas objects' `.plot()` precisely return the `ax` you're looking for, as in:

```
plt1 = pd.Series(range(2)).plot()
color = plt1.lines[-1].get_color()
pd.Series(range(2, 4)).plot(color=color)
```

[image]

This is not much nicer, but might allow you to avoid importing matplotlib explicitly